# UnboundLocalError inside inner function

Tags: python

I am new to Python but I am experienced Java programmer. I cant figure why in below code the UnboundLocalError refers to a but not b.

```
def outer():
  a = str()
  b = list()
  def inner():
    b.append(a)
    if len(a)==0:
      a = 'text'
      inner()
  inner()  


>>>outer()

      3   b = list()
      4   def inner():
----> 5     b.append(a)
      6     if len(a)==0:
      7       a = 'text'

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `a` is assumed to be a variable local to `inner()` because you assign to it inside `inner()`.

Comment: Put `nonlocal a` at the top of `inner`.